# Cloudwatch Alarm Denied Access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

so i have an sns with my email and a link to ops genie, tested and working fine for "regular" alarms. Now i installed the Metrics script on my ec2 server using this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html

and now i can see certain metrics on my metrics tab in the cloudwatch tab. but when i set an alarm for "disk space" for example, and when it was trigerred i got this error: "

> Failed to execute action
>   arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:account-no:Email_List. Received
>   error: "null (Service: AWSKMS; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
>   AccessDeniedException; Request ID:
>   3a2f1086-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-42e31dcc849b)"

i also created an IAM policy and user from this link: https://dev.to/idrisrampurawala/monitoring-memory-and-disk-metrics-for-aws-ec2-instances-2eg2

which allowed me to send the metrics to my cloudwatch metrics tabs, but im not sure why the alarm doesn't work for metric sets, but only for regular alarms.

Am i missing anything here? if so what is it?
Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

That error message indicates a KMS error. Is the SNS topic encrypted using a KMS key?

I so, you need to alter the KMS key policy to be used by the principal cloudwatch.amazonaws.com